# How to set up a LSTM network with only one input an time 0 for Sequence Generation?

Tags: python, keras

I set up a training set with X of shape (batch_size, 50) and Y of shape (batch_size, 10(sequence length), 10(output vector)).

The Keras Documentation of the LSTM cell says, that a 3D input is required, but Sequence 2 Sequence models work and do exactly this. Is there another common way to address this task?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(50,)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10, activation='softmax')))
```

I get the error: "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"

Answer (score 1):

This return only the last step of the Sequence, you should set the argument: 
**return_sequences=True**

For the following model:

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(1, 50), return_sequences=True))
 model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10, activation='softmax')))
```

I Have:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 50)             20200     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 1, 10)             510       
=================================================================
Total params: 20,710
Trainable params: 20,710
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You are right, but this has no effect on the input.

Comment: Have you tried performing a reshape on your input and setting **input_shape=(50, 1)** ?

Comment: I have reshaped each batch to (batch_size, 1, 50) and set input_shape=(1, 50). Now I get an error from the TimeDistributed layer: "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have shape (1, 10) but got array with shape (10, 10)"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input_shape to (1, 50) and adding a

`model.add(RepeatVector(10, input_shape=(50, )))`

as first layer, fixes the problem. The additional RepeatVector makes the input visible to the network at all times step.

A good overview over Keras LSTM nets is:
[How to use return_sequences option and TimeDistributed layer in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755820/how-to-use-return-sequences-option-and-timedistributed-layer-in-keras)